# Where should I store user uploaded files nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, storage

In my app I have a list of customers, and I want to be able to attach files to customers and for them to be saved on their profile.
The files will be png, jpg or pdf.

I'm using vue, nodejs and mongodb.
a few possible solutions I am considering:

- Saving the files in a folder on the server - sounds unscalable. I don't want to lose control over the space in my server.
- Storing the files as binary data in mongodb
- Storing the files on AWS S3
- Using a third-party service like Cloudinary

I'm wondering which is the best way.
Regurding the last two, if anyone has any information about the pricing please share.

Would love to hear your thoughts on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why was it voted down, and with no additional explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I think here we need more requirements, but if you are using other AWS services - the best way is to use S3 as file storage and save links in the database (MongoDB or whatever) for download.

Comment: At the moment I don't use any other AWS services. the app is stored on a private server.
About the other requirements, the files, at the moment, are not limited by size, they will be sent to the admin by email or whatsapp to be uploaded, So I have no way of predicting their size. I will add some size validation or maybe compress it before uploading in the future (here services like Cloudinary comes in handy).
For now I'm just trying to understand in which direction I should go.